# ADO.NET transaction handling

Tags: c#, ado.net

Please let me know your feedback around handling ADO.NET connection and transaction, especially when it comes the `catch` block. Any way I could improve?

```
public static bool FileBulkLoad(string filePath, string tableName, string fieldSeparator, int numberOfSourceColumns)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var fileData in Helpers.StreamFile(filePath, tableName, fieldSeparator, numberOfSourceColumns))
                {
                    // BulkInsert uses SqlBulkCopy to insert data.
                    Helpers.BulkInsert(fileData.Data, tableName, connection, transaction);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileBulkLoad` isn't an ideal name for a method - it's a *noun*, and nouns should be used for naming *types* - method names should be *verbs*, because they *do* something.

The fact that it's `static` is also worrying - less so than that static `Helpers`, but worrying nonetheless: you're coupling your application logic with a specific data access strategy, which means you have no way of writing a unit test for your application logic without actually hitting the database and, in this case, the file system.

Consider this alternative:

```
public interface IFilePersistenceService
{
    bool LoadFromDelimitedFile(string path, string separator, int columns);
}
```

Now you can implement this interface with a class that will use `Helpers.BulkInsert` with ADO.NET, or one that uses a UnitOfWork and Entity Framework, or NHibernate, or whatever: the point is that *bulk insert* is a mere implementation detail that the rest of your code doesn't need to care about - that's why having it in the method's name doesn't really bring anything to the table.

Your client code would be written against this `IFilePersistenceService` abstraction, and then you could *inject* a fake implementation of that interface into your application logic, and write tests that don't hit the file system or a database.

---

I said `Helpers` was worrisome; the name doesn't convey anything but "stuff that serves some purpose, somewhere" - after a while it becomes a dumping ground for any code that doesn't quite belong elsewhere, or for anything that you need to access from anywhere - and that's how spaghettification begins.

Consider killing that (static?) class, with fire.

---

The implementation itself isn't half bad: you are disposing of disposables, using `using` blocks - it doesn't get any better than that IMO.

The problem is at a higher level: you're returning `true` on success, `false` on failure - and once the client code knows the operation failed, it doesn't know anything about the failure, that was all swallowed by the called method.

I'd **much** rather return `void` and have code that either works or blows up.

The Boolean return value is more hurtful than anything, it's the client code that knows how to handle an exception (e.g. display a message to the user about a permission issue, or email tech support with exception details, whatever): it's the client code that should wrap this method call with a `try/catch` block. Or the method should log the exception details and then rethrow.

---

I would expect a "load" method to *fetch* data from a data source, and *return* that data to the application. Perhaps this would be more appropriate:

```
public interface IFilePersistenceService
{
    void ImportFile(string path, string separator, int columns);
}
```

Right? You're *importing* data into a database, from a file.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed analysis! I definitely learned something.

Answer (score 1):

It looks much cleaner with the [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        foreach (var fileData in Helpers.StreamFile(filePath, tableName, fieldSeparator, numberOfSourceColumns))
        {
            // BulkInsert uses SqlBulkCopy to insert data.
            Helpers.BulkInsert(fileData.Data, tableName, connection, transaction);
        }

        scope.Complete();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You should also read this: [Is it possible to use System.Transactions.TransactionScope with SqlBulkCopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311494/235671)

The last parameter is unnecessary.

---

**Exception handling**

Are you sure you want to ignore the exception? I guess you log it somehow, do you?